# SSIS foreach loop, continue but also perform an action on failed iteration?

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis

I'm attempting to write an SSIS package that will perform an audit on some servers.  When the audit finishes, it emails the sys admin responsible for the server telling them that an audit has been performed and where they can find the reportings of the audit.

The issue I'm running into is that when an audit fails for whatever reason (can't connect to the server and whatnot), I would like to send the sys admin an email saying that it failed.  It'd be nice to say where it failed too, but if I have to settle for a simple "it failed" email, then that's okay too.  As long as they know that it hasn't been run.

So I overcame the 'continuing the foreach loop' on failure by adding the error handler in which the variable propagate is set to false.

How can I get the task to send an email on failure?  Do I have to add a "OnError" event handler for every single task within the foreach loop (29 tasks)?  Or is there some magical "on failed iteration perform this task"?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe use a container to set the OnError Event only on the container

Comment: @mxix will this work for the propagate too?

Comment: @mxix Just tested it, doesn't work.  The issue is that to continue a foreach loop, you must disable propagate on the failing component (the task within the foreach) and this causes the foreach to actually succeed - therefore no errors are caught because there "weren't any errors".

Answer (score 1):

So after some more in depth searching - it seems the answer is to simply perform error handling on every component within the foreach loop.  Nice because it allows for detailed error reporting ("Failed *here*"), annoying because it's a lot of components in my case.

**For anyone googling this later:
To stop a foreach loop from failing on task failure:**

- Select the failing task and click on 'Event Handlers' next to 'Parameters' on the top of your package designer.
- On the drop down under "Event Handler:" select 'OnError' (it should already be the one selected) then click the blue text in the middle of the package designer 'Click here to create an 'OnError' event handler for executable 'Your component name''
- Navigate to the variables pane (SSIS -> Variables).
- When in variables click the 'Grid Options' button on the top of the variable pane.
- Check 'Show system variables'.  Click okay.
- Scroll down to 'Propogate', set this to False.
- Repeat for any components that you think may fail.

**To handle error reporting**

- For each component that you have added an OnError event handler, place components within the event handler to report in your favourite method of reporting, email, place error in a database, whatever.

Your foreach loop will now continue even if an Event Handled component fails.  When the component fails, it will execute the components within it's respective Event Handler.

Hope this helps anyone searching in the future.

Edit: Please note that a failed component (if the flow is directed) will fail the **whole iteration**.  This means if you have necessary tasks to be performed even on one failing, do not direct the task flow.  If you would like a single component failing to fail the whole iteration (my case), then direct the task flow by connecting them in order of precedence.